# Javascript weird nested assignment issue in a object literal

Tags: javascript-objects, javascript

I have a JS object property defined in an object literal:

```
reqHeader: [{name:'Chris'},{age:'06'}]
```

which I am nesting inside another property in the same object literal:

```
content: {headers:
              {reqHeader: this.reqHeader}
          },
```

Now when I try to access this from a method in the same object literal, it says it is undefined:

```
getHeaders: function(){
    var a = this.content['headers']['reqHeader'];
    alert(a);
}
```

Full code: http://jsfiddle.net/Amnesiac/zZP83/5/

Thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That won't work, because `this` is not a reference to that object. That is, it is **not** the case that JavaScript sets `this` to refer to an object that's "under construction" inside the object literal block. It remains set to whatever it is outside that expression.

What you can do is something like:

```
var obj = {
  reqHeaders: /* whatever */,
  content: {
    headers: {
    }
  }
};

obj.content.headers.reqHeader = obj.reqHeader;
```

Answer (score 1):

@Pointy is right, `this` in your case means global object, but not the `obj` object, if you want to have `this` referred to your `obj`, you need to make it an instance of some class/function:

```
var obj= new (function a(){

    this.reqHeader = [{name:'Chris'},{age:'06'}];

    this.content = {headers:{reqHeader:this.reqHeader}

            };

    this.getHeaders = function(){
        var a = this.content['headers']['reqHeader'];
        alert(a);
    };

});

obj.getHeaders();
```

here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/podlipensky/zZP83/9/) for this

Answer (score 1):

In your JsFiddle you have:

```
var obj={

    reqHeader: [{name:'Chris'},{age:'06'}],

    content: {
        headers: {
            reqHeader:this.reqHeader
        }
    },

    getHeaders: function(){
        var a = this.content['headers']['reqHeader'];
        alert(a);
    }
}

obj.getHeaders();
```

But when you reference `this.reqHeader` inside the definition of `content.headers.reqHeader`, the `this` variable doesn't point to the main object. Indeed, if you chance that line to this:

```
    content: {
        headers: {
            reqHeader: 'Hello!'
        }
    },
```

it will work, and will alert the word `Hello!`.